# how to show/hide elements based on user role without using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-web-api

I am using a MVC 5 /Web Api project with entity framework. I turned it into a Angular SPA project and I want to know how I can pull the logged in user info without using razor.cshtml. I want to show/hide elements based on the user roles. I would think it would need to be a service that pulls the server side data and convert it to javascript? I have found a couple examples doing this but they are based on empty MVC projects not using entity framework. 
So I would basically need something like this, but in Angular

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("Editor"))
{
 <div>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</div>
}
<div>@Html.ActionLink("Generate Report", "Report")</div>
<div>@Html.ActionLink("Other Stuff", "Other")</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many choices but the principal is that you will have to store the users role on the client.

Depending on your situation this could be stored in a cookie, local storage or you Angular model.

IMHO it would be most declarative to store within your Angular model.  Assuming your server calls are authenticated you would simply return the user's roles as part of the json to populate your Angular model.

Comment: so i would make a api get call to the users table? what is the api url?

Comment: do you not already make a call when they log in?  you could extend this to include their roles.